# Problems with scrollTop animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three divs, each one with some hidden content. When you click on a div, its content is being displayed by sliding down. And at the same time, I'm using scrollTop to make the browser scroll to the top of the block thats been clicked on. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="blocks block1"></div>
<div class="content block1_content"></div>

<div class="blocks block2"></div>
<div class="content block2_content"></div>

<div class="blocks block3"></div>
<div class="content block3_content"></div>
```

However, im having problems with parts of the scrollTop animation. Here is the JS:

```
$('.blocks').on("click", function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
    collapseExpandedFunction();

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 500);

    $(this).addClass('expanded');

    $(this).next().slideDown();
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
    collapseExpandedFunction();

  }
});

collapseExpandedFunction = function() {
  $('.blocks.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
  $('.content').slideUp();
};
```

I made an jsfiddle to easier demonstrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ss53ckyk/3/

**Explaination:**

If you start toggle the green block and then toggle the red or blue, it's all good. The greens content is being hidden, while the red/blue is displayed and scrolled to the top of the block.

The problem is if you start from the top and moving down. If you first toggle the red one and then either blue or green, the browser won't scroll down correctly.

Another thing i'd like is to make the slideDown happen after the scrollTop animation is done.

Hopefully someone can help me out!

**EDIT:**

There should only be one blocks content visible at a time. For example, if you click the red once and then the blue, the content of the red should slide up, while the blue is showing.

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous nature of javascript is causing your issues; namely *.slidUp()* function. When this event is triggered, it fires an asynchronous event, which is non-blocking to the rest of the function. Therefore, the animate top will take a snapshot of the DOM at a particular moment in time while the *.slidUp()* function is actioning. Replacing the .slidUp() and .slidDown() with .show() and .hide() to resolve this, but this doesn't provide the responsiveness you require. One thought would be to capture the offsets of each previous content div and use that in the scrollTop function.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :

Based on the edit, you need to make few adjustments in your code which calculates the `scrolltop` position based on `scrollposition` and adding margin based on the corresponding `.content` div

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var addMargin = false;

  $('.blocks').on("click", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('expanded')) {     
       collapseExpandedFunction();

      var doc = document.documentElement;
      var ele = this;     
      var nextEle = $(ele).next();

      $(this).addClass('expanded');      

      var margin = 0;
      var scrollTo = 0;     


     if($(ele).hasClass('expanded'))
      {
          if(addMargin)
             margin = $(nextEle).css('height').replace('px',''); 
          scrollTo = $(ele).offset().top - margin;               
      }          

      if(doc.scrollTop != 0 && doc.scrollTop > scrollTo && addMargin)
      {
          console.log(margin);
         scrollTo = scrollTo + 200;
      }

   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo
      }, 500, function()
      {          
         $(ele).next().slideDown();
      });       

    } else if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
        collapseExpandedFunction();
    }    

  });

  collapseExpandedFunction = function() 
  {
    $('.blocks.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
    $('.content').slideUp();
    addMargin = false;
  };

  window.onscroll = function (e) {  
   addMargin = true; 
} 

});
```

Here's the working code : https://jsfiddle.net/ss53ckyk/13/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, works a lot better now, altough there's still one problem. The collapseExpandedFunction() was there to make all the other blocks contents to slide up. There should only be one block content visible at a time. For example, if you click the red once and then the blue, the content of the red should slide up, while the blue is showing. Any idea how to solve his? ... Edited the post with this.

Comment: @qua1ity: I've updated the solution. Hope this works for you.